# Read a map N keys at a time

Tags: java

I have a map (instaWords) which is filled with thousands of words. I need to to loop over it N item at a time. Here is my code. In this code I need to read instaWords in the chunks of e.g 500 words and execute "updateInstaPhrases" with those words. Any help?

```
private static Map<InstaWord, List<Integer>> instaWords = new HashMap<InstaWord, List<Integer>>();

// here a couple of words are added to instaWords

updateInstaPhrases(instaWords);      

private static void updateInstaPhrases(Map<InstaWord, List<Integer>> wordMap)                             
throws SQLException, UnsupportedEncodingException {                                    
  for (Map.Entry<InstaWord, List<Integer>> entry : wordMap.entrySet()) {             
      InstaWord instaWord = entry.getKey();                                     
      List<Integer> profiles = entry.getValue();                                    
      pst.setBytes(1, instaWord.word.getBytes("UTF-8"));                          
      pst.setBytes(2, instaWord.word.getBytes("UTF-8"));                          
      pst.setBytes(3, (instaWord.lang == null) ?·                                 
       "".getBytes("UTF-8") :·                                                      
       instaWord.lang.getBytes("UTF-8"));                                         
      String profilesList = "";                                                     
      boolean first = true;                                                         
      for (Integer p : profiles) {                                                  
          profilesList += (first ? "" : ", ") + p;                                        
          first = false;                                                                  
      }                                                                             
      pst.setString(4, profilesList);                                               
      pst.addBatch();                                                               
  }                                                                                 
System.out.println("Words batch executed");                                         
pst.executeBatch();                                               
con.commit();                                                                       
}
```

What I need is to iterate through a hashmap 'in chunks' (e.g. 500 item each time)

Comment: You should probably fix your indentation so that it makes sense.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know... HashMaps don't have any specific order to them. This could mean that iterating over chunks of it at a time may not work correctly if it has been modified. If this did become an issue, an OrderedHashMap would be appropriate.

Comment: @khelwood I did fix it as much as I could

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson why it should be modified? I just have this Hashmap and I'd to iterate over it a chunk at a time. Does it work correctly? I can't easily change this to OrderedHashMap.

Comment: In this current use-case I don't think it's a problem since you aren't inserting/removing anything while you're reading from the hashmap. It was just a word of warning to prevent future issues.

Comment: I would start out by extracting some of those things into their own methods. It's extremely difficult to debug a method when it's doing so many things at once.

Comment: Why are you using `setBytes` instead of `setString`? Is it because you don't understand how character encoding works? Or because your database doesn't support UTF-8?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson thanks for the warning. I believe I just need a simple loop over a Hashmap with a chunk, the rest is just for giving the big picture and is unnecessary.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for your suggestion this is legacy code and I need to update it but at the moment that's not my current question.

Comment: @PHA do you remove the words from instaWords after collecting chunk wordMap?

Comment: I don’t think I understand your problem well enough to help. I’d prefer a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including more precise description of expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: @user1111527 yes it could be removed.

Comment: @OleV.V. What I need is simply to iterate through a hashmap 'in chunks' imagine a hashmap with 5000 item and you need to iterate over it but after iterating on 500th item you do a sleep for and then continue the next 500 item. So after 10 sleep the program iterates over all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may keep a counter, initialize to 0 and increment for each item, while collecting the items as you see fit (like, say, `ArrayList<Map.Entry<InstaWord, List<Integer>>>`). If counter (after increment) equals 500, process the whole batch, reset counter to 0 and clear the collection.

Another option is to have the counter control the loop and declare explicitly the iterator you draw the `Map.Entry`s from. In this way it’s probably a bit clearer what is going on.